# How to count and display total value between intervals when using maxTicksLimit option in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a dynamic chart which might contain hundreds of datasets, in which case I need to reduce quantity of elements to make it readable. I was looking for a solution and I found the `maxTicksLimit` option in `Chart.js` documentation to reduce labels quantity on x axis, but now I need to calculate total count of data between the intervals and display this value in the center of the interval. But could not find anything. The fiddle shows labels as 0, 15, 30, 45... And all records in dataset. But i need to display total count between 0 and 15, 16 and 30, etc... How can I do it using `Chart.js` library itself?

```js
var data = [];
var labels = [];
var quantity = 150;
for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
  var test = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  data.push(test);
  labels.push(i);
}

new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            data: data,
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    maxTicksLimit: 10
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="800" height="400" style="background: #202020"></canvas>
```

Here is the fiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/L0dbqnz8/

Comment: Newer versions of `chart.js` include ["data decimation"](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.2/configuration/decimation.html) algorithms that might be useful for the case that you have huge datasets. As for counting the data points, you have to do it yourself; if the issue is that you don't know beforehand where the ticks will be, you can do the counting in a [callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.2/axes/#callbacks) e.g., `afterBuildTicks`

Answer (score 0):

What i found is if we want to modify the tick marks or label, we can use ticks.callback method in the axis configuration

Refer: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html

But since we wan't in the mid of label, we can tweak it a bit like

```
callback: function (value, index, values) {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    return value;
  }
  return "Total Count";
}
```

but it reduces the maxTicksLimit by half